# Hiding classes when clicking an option in the nav

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, i have a bootstrap website where i want to post news and other content. i have a navbar at the top, with a few options being Home, Videos, News, and Interesting. When i click on Videos, i want it to filter the content i've posted below with only articles that have the Videos class. and then when i click News, it should swap out and show only News class articles and so on. The Home option should show everything.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="filter">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" id="All">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="News">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="Interesting">Interesting</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="ourHolder">
        <article class="Videos">
            <p>lipsum orum dio grande</p>
        </article>

        <article class="News">
            <p>lipsum orum dio grande</p>
        </article>

        <article class="Videos">
            <p>lipsum orum dio grande</p>
        </article>

        <article class="Interesting">
            <p>lipsum orum dio grande</p>
        </article>
    </div>

</body>
```

Now for the jQuery, i'm not too sure how to get it working. so far ive just got it to where when you click an item it becomes active. i cannot figure out how to have it hide the other classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#filter li').click(function() {
      $('#filter .active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

});
```

Any input is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `.not()` method is your friend here http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#filter li a').click(function () {
        $('#filter .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        filterClass = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(filterClass);
        if (filterClass == 'All') {
            $('article').show();
        } else {
            // Get all that are NOT your chosen class and hide
            $('article').not('.' + filterClass).hide();
            // Now show only the articles that have class = filterClass
            $('article.' + filterClass).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. the code seems to make sense to me, but when i implement it, i cannot get it to work? http://jsfiddle.net/RU4QW/

Comment: Here is a working fiddle, there were a few things, the selector was targeting the `li` and not the `a` hence wasn't getting an `id` attribute value.  Also your fiddle wasn't including jQuery and there was a syntax error discovered running jsHint http://jsfiddle.net/RU4QW/3/